# Evaluate $\iint_R y^{e^{xy}}$ where $R = [-1,0] \times [-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

In the book 'A Friendly Introduction to Analysis,' in a section on iterated integrals, the following exercise appears:

Evaluate $\iint_R y^{e^{xy}}$ where $R = [-1,0] \times [-1,1]$

I'm troubled as to how to solve this. In the end of the book the answer is given as: $2 + e^{-1} - e$. I can't find out how to get there.

The most important theorem of this section is *Fubini's theorem*.

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

EDIT: We have come to the conclusion that there has been very likely made a typo in the exercise. I suppose this question is not really of use to anyone anymore.

Comment: Integration is defined only with or over an infitesimal change, denoted usually as $dxdy$ or $dxdx$ etc.

Comment: This notation is used in the book to indicate an integration over the rectangle $R$. Now I think that indeed either the integral to $dx$ or $dy$ should be evaluated first, in order to apply Furbini's theorem. But I can solve neither of the integrals.

Comment: You should explain or use correct notation.

Comment: This is correct notation for an integral over a region..

Comment: How so? Why don't you back up your claim, instead. Or where you preparing to have a long battle of no it's not?

Comment: An integral represents a sum over a function in which an infitesimal amount is summed. It's crucial part of the limit definition of an integral. With out it, it has no meaning. There are many types of integration just for double integral. Depending on the type of differential.

Comment: I can't seem to find examples but this is what my book uses rather frequently. This is the exact way the problem was stated. I think however that you're right and $dxdy$ or $dydx$ would make it better. Maybe the exercise should be that, given that Furbini's theorem holds, you need to calculate either the integral to $dxdy$ or $dydx$ to your choice.

Comment: Well I prefer to stick with notation that has concrete meaning, that won't change to who knows what after I've invested some time into one possibility. Also if the author is in a process of explaining the motivation and rigorous definitions. It may have some meaning then. But that would require more information or the whole section from that book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo, either in the book or in what you put here. The problem is meant to be 
$$\iint_R ye^{xy}\,dA,$$
where $R=[-1,0]\times [-1,1]$. One order of integration is clearly far easier, so I suggest you use that. Oh, and this does give the book's answer, I think. :)

Comment: I had just noticed that, because another user solved that integral and came to the exact answer the book gave. The typo is in the book, and this is definitely solvable for me. Thanks for putting this in an answer.

Comment: You're welcome. I wanted to put you out of your agony. P.S.  It's Fubini (no r).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Maybe the question should be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

$$\iint_R ye^{xy}\,\mathrm dA=\int_{-1}^0\int_{-1}^1ye^{xy}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$

Provided you can show that Fubini's theorem holds, you can swap the order of the integration to get

$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^0ye^{xy}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=\int_{-1}^1(1-e^{-y})\,\mathrm dy=2-2\sinh1$$

Comment: It's $y^{e^{xy}}$, not $ye^{xy}$. Also for Furbini's theorem there's one condition that the function must be Riemann integrable on $R$ but I think that is implied by the asking of the question itself.

Comment: Hey I see your answer is back. Although it doesn't answer my question it actually contributed to understanding that the question had a typo in it. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh cool so the answer was what? To What your text book ask, the answer in back of book? Or simply that your text book has typos?